# Proving that if L is regular. Then L′ = {ww : w ∈ L} is regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

I believe this statement to be true. And here's my reasoning:

> Based on regular languages properties, the concatenation of two regular languages is regular. And since L′ = L · L, it follows that L′ must also be regular.

Do you think my reasoning is valid?

Comment: The statement is false, and so your reasoning must be invalid. Consider $L=a^*b$.

Comment: With $L= \Sigma^*$, $L'$ is the most famous example for non-context-free languages.

Comment: This question appears to be unsuited for this site because questions of the form: "This is the exercise problem, this is my solution. Please grade!" are not interesting for anyone but you. Please see [this related meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/597/), and [these hints](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/) on asking questions about exercise problems. If you want to ask a *specific* question about a *specific* part of your attempt, please edit the question accordingly and it may be reopened. Otherwise, you might want to visit [chat] and get some feedback there.

Comment: @Raphael I think this question is fine. The reasoning here is IMO specific enough to directly address. I don't even see how to ask a more specific question than this. Also, the reasoning is concise enough to be directly answerable, as can be seen in Yuval's answer.

Comment: It's a yes/no question. Answering 'yes' or 'no' is not very informative.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The statement is false. Consider the language $L = \{a^n b : n \geq 0\}$. Then $L' = \{ a^n b a^n b : n \geq 0 \}$ is not regular (exercise).

The invalid point in your reasoning is a confusion between the following two languages: $L' = \{ ww : w \in L \}$ and $L'' = \{ w_1w_2 : w_1,w_2 \in L \}$. It is $L''$ which is the concatenation of $L$ with itself. Whereas $L'$ need not be regular, $L''$ is always regular when $L$ is.

Comment: would you be willing to chat in the cs chat room to discuss?